# The variable punkte (points) return 0 at the end of the program. What am I doing wrong and what can I do to make it come out as the actual score?

Tags: python-3.x

```
punkte = int()
print("Do you want to answer a quiz?")
z = input()
a = str(z)
if a == "Yes":
    print("Question?")
    z = input()
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 1
    elif a != "Answer":
        print("Question?")
        z = input()
        if a == "Answer":
            punkte = punkte + 1
        elif a != "Answer":
            print("Question?")
            z = input()
            if a == "Answer":
                punkte = punkte +2 
            elif a != "Answer":
                print("Question?")
                z = input()
                if a == "Answer":
                    punkte = punkte + 2 
                elif a != "Answer":
                    print("Question?")
                    z = input() 
                    if a == "Answer":
                        punkte = punkte + 3 
                    elif a != "Answer":
                        print("That was the last question.You have reached",punkte,"points")
```

This asks the user if he wants to answer a quiz.If he answers "yes" he will be asked a few questions.The variable "punkte" is supposed to change and store points based on the answer. At the end it still comes out as 0.

Comment: Good for you...

Comment: You never asked a question.

Comment: All of your question replies are going into `z`, yet you are always checking `a` for the answer.  OF COURSE none of those conditions are true, as `a` is still "Yes" from the one time in the program where you actually set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you only keep asking questions as long as the user gives an answer that is not "Yes" (except for the initial question). Only then will you print the score, which obviously is 0 (since only answers with "Yes" are counted). As soon as "Yes" is given as answer you increase the number of points from 0 to 1 and don't do anything else.

First you should make sure you test the actual answer that was given (`z`) and don't keep testing the first answer again and again (`a`).

Secondly, the `elif` kind of statements are breaking the chain: they prevent the program from continuing with the chain of questions when a right answer has been given. NB: the condition `a != "Answer"` is useless, as at that point that is always implied (true).

It will work better without those `elif` and without `z` -- use `a` all the way:

```
punkte = 0
print("Do you want to answer a quiz?")
a = input()
if a == "Yes":
    print("Question?")
    a = input()
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 1
    print("Question?")
    a = input()
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 1
    print("Question?")
    a = input()
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 2 
    print("Question?")
    a = input()
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 2 
    print("Question?")
    a = input() 
    if a == "Answer":
        punkte = punkte + 3 
    print("That was the last question.You have reached",punkte,"points")
```

You should look into using a list structure for your questions, correct answers and points to gain for them, and then loop over them. That will make your program shorter, more flexible and easier to maintain.

For instance:

```
punkte = 0
quiz = [{
        "question": "1. What is the capital of France?",
        "answer": "Paris",
        "score": 1
    }, {
        "question": "2. How many keys does a standard piano have?",
        "answer": "88",
        "score": 3
    }, {
        "question": "3. Which day of the week is also called the Sabbath?",
        "answer": "Saturday",
        "score": 1
    }, {
        "question": "4. Which is name of the brightest star as seen from the Earth?",
        "answer": "Sirius",
        "score": 3
    }]
print("Do you want to answer a quiz?")
a = input()
if a == "Yes":
    for q in quiz:
        print(q["question"])
        a = input()
        if a == q["answer"]:
            punkte = punkte + q["score"]
    print("That was the last question. You earned",punkte,"points")
```